# Add element in Xml with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

**Need to add this element `<ColourAddon>red</ColourAddon>` inside GSIset in the following xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<GSIExplorer>
  <GSISet>
    <ID>local</ID>
    <GSIServer>localhost</GSIServer>
    <ALERT_TIMEOUT>30</ALERT_TIMEOUT>
  </GSISet>
</GSIExplorer>
```

**the code am using is this:**

```
 [xml]$Xmlnew = Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\GSI\gsiSettings\gsiPSSSettings2.xml"
        $test = $Xmlnew.CreateElement("ColourAddon","red")
        $Xmlnew.GSIExplorer.GSISet.AppendChild($test)
        $Xmlnew.save("C:\Program Files (x86)\GSI\gsiSettings\gsiPSSSettings3.xml")
```

**the result i get is this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<GSIExplorer>
  <GSISet>
    <ID>local</ID>
    <GSIServer>localhost</GSIServer>
    <ALERT_TIMEOUT>30</ALERT_TIMEOUT>
    <Colouraddon xmlns="asda" />
  </GSISet>
</GSIExplorer>
```

**and i want this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <GSIExplorer>
      <GSISet>
        <ID>local</ID>
        <GSIServer>localhost</GSIServer>
        <ALERT_TIMEOUT>30</ALERT_TIMEOUT>
        <ColourAddon>red</ColourAddon>
      </GSISet>
    </GSIExplorer>
```

**any help?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create the element, then set the value.

```
[xml]$Xmlnew = Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\GSI\gsiSettings\gsiPSSSettings2.xml"
$test = $Xmlnew.CreateElement("ColourAddon")

# thanks to Jeroen Mostert's helpful comment. original at bottom of post [1]
$Xmlnew.GSIExplorer.GSISet.AppendChild($test).InnerText = "red" 

$Xmlnew.save("C:\Program Files (x86)\GSI\gsiSettings\gsiPSSSettings3.xml")
```

**Related:** [`CreateElement` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_CreateElement_System_String_System_String_). Note how the two values refer to name and namespace, not name and "value" or "text" or similar.

```
# [1] original answer
$Xmlnew.GSIExplorer.GSISet.AppendChild($test)
$Xmlnew.GSIExplorer.GSISet.ColourAddon = "red"
```

Comment: Or `$Xmlnew.GSIExplorer.GSISet.AppendChild($test).InnerText = "red"`, with the added benefit of not having to suppress or store the output of `AppendChild`.

Comment: `[xml]$Xmlnew = Get-Content "some.xml"` is a bad way of loading an XML document. `Get-Content` does not honor the encoding declaration in the XML file, but uses your system's default encoding to read the file. All bets are off if that works or not, it will silently mangle your data if it doesn't work. Please always use the XML parser itself to load the file: `$Xmlnew = New-Object xml; $Xmlnew.Load("some.xml")`. Only this way guarantees that the encoding is honored in all cases.

Comment: thank you all for solution and mainly for explanation. really helpful.